# Is there a name for this property of groups?

Tags: group-theory, terminology, permutation-cycles

Is there a name for the property of a permutation* group of a set S*, $G$, such that:

> For at least one permutation $\alpha \in G$ and at least one $i$ of S*: $\alpha(i)\neq i$, but the transposition $(\alpha(i) \ i)\notin G$.

(Cyclic groups like $\mathbb{Z}_4$ have this property, and so does e.g. $D_4$.)

Or a name for this property?

> For all $\alpha \in G$, if $\alpha(i)\neq i$, then $(\alpha(i) \ i) \in G$ and at least one $\alpha \in G, \alpha(i)\neq i$?

Or, names for properties equivalent to these?

(*) edited

Comment: First of all, any terminology on this would likely be about *group actions*, not groups as such. Or maybe terminology specific to permutation groups.

Comment: What is $i$ in these statements? What does the notation $\alpha(i)$ refer to? What does $(a\ b)\in G$ mean, when $G$ is an arbitrary group?

Comment: Thank you for your help! Milten and Christoph and user 1729. I meant to be talking about permutation groups of a set, and i is supposed to be a member of the given set. I will edit the question to let this clearer. Please let me know if I can clarify anything else.

Comment: That's much clearer now (although I suggest removing the [square brackets] as they make it a bit confusing to read!).

Comment: Done! Thank you!

Comment: It looks to me as though most permutation groups have that property. In fact the only groups that do not are those that act as the symmetric group on $S \setminus {\rm Fix}(G)$, where ${\rm Fix}(G)$ is the set of points of $S$ that are fixed by every $g \in G$. But I am not sure why you would expect there to be a name for groups that satisfy the property.

Comment: @DerekHolt I believe there's a bit more freedom than that – though not much. (See my answer)

Comment: Yes you are correct. I couldn't make much sense of the second condition myself (what if the $i$ in $\alpha(i) \ne i$ at the end?)

Answer (score 2):

**[Edited the infinite case]**

Your two properties are the negation of each other, and the second one is the rare one – though not quite as rare as Derek Holt claims. I don't really think there's a name for this, but we can at least classify the such *finite* permutation groups pretty easily.

Assume $G$ is finite and has the second property. Let $\mathcal O(a)=\{\alpha(a)\mid\alpha\in G\}$ be the orbit of $a$. Then $G$ contains all transpositions of elements in $\mathcal O(a)$, since if $b,c\in \mathcal O(a)$, say $b=\alpha(a)$ and $c=\beta(a)$, then
$$
b=\alpha(\beta^{-1}(c)) \implies (b\ c)\in G.
$$
But that means $G$ has a subgroup acting as the symmetric group on $\mathcal O(a)$.

So let $\mathcal O_1,\ldots,\mathcal O_k$ be the orbits of $G$ (assume for now there are finitely many orbits). Then $G$ is isomorphic to a direct product of symmetric groups,
$$
G \cong S_{|\mathcal O_1|} \times \cdots \times S_{|\mathcal O_k|}.
$$
To prove this, we need to show that the symmetric subgroups are normal, essentially disjoint, and generate $G$ – which is all easy.

---

If $G$ is infinite there is more freedom. If we assume all the orbits $\mathcal O_i$, $i\in I$ are finite, then we can say that
$$
\bigoplus_{i\in I} Sym(\mathcal O_i) \le G\le \prod_{i\in I} Sym(\mathcal O_i),
$$
where the above are a direct sum and a direct product. If there are orbits of infinite cardinality, then the transpositions don't generate symmetric groups, so the situation is even more open. I think we then can say
$$
\bigoplus_{i\in I} FSym(\mathcal O_i) \le G\le \prod_{i\in I} Sym(\mathcal O_i),
$$
where $FSym(S)$ is the finitary symmetric group on the set $S$. But I haven't thought it all the way through.